# R: aggregate over rows if X is less than value, don't aggregate if not

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate some data in R according to a particular column. 
Example data are below.

```
> d <- data.frame(POS=c(1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5), Dist=c(111,6,9,58,250,4,65,111),Read=c(1,2,6,6,25,1,8,11))
> print(d)
  POS Dist Read
1   1  111    1
2   2    6    2
3   2    9    6
4   2   58    6
5   3  250   25
6   4    4    1
7   4   65    8
8   5  111   11
```

What I'd like to do is calculate the mean across rows according to column Reads only if the Distance column is less than 100. So, under POS column, I'd like row 1 to be left alone as group 1, then to calculate the mean of rows 2, 3, & 4, row 5 to be left alone as group 3, then to calculate the mean of row 6 & 7 (mean = 4.5) of group 4.

The 'real' data set does not have the POS column, and is >24,000 rows long, so I'd rather not identify which rows should be averaged by hand.

Comment: You could try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, M := mean(W23540_02[Distance..2.1. < 100]), by = POS][is.na(M), M := as.double(W23540_02)]`, though I'm not sure how did you come up with that `55.7` there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this should do it.

df means data frame, or the object that you have your data stored in.

```
library(dplyr)

summary_dataset <- d %>% filter(Dist < 100) %>% group_by(POS) %>% summarize(Mean = mean(Read))
```

To bind these summary values onto the dataset, just use this.

```
d$Mean <- summary_dataset$Mean[match(d$POS, summary_dataset$POS)]
```

Also, I'm sure there is an easier way of doing this than what I did. There should be a simple one liner of code that does this, but that I am unaware of.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this!  I added a dataset and tried to better explain the issue I'm having.

Comment: Okay, so I adjusted my code for what you asked. Does it do the job?

Comment: Good to hear, glad to help!

Comment: The OP has updated their post, and I can't now see a "column M". Bear in mind that meta-commentary isn't very useful for future readers - if you have feedback on the quality of the question, please add it as a comment under the question. I'll edit this, but do feel free to edit further.